# Rotating row and column in dataframe in R

Tags: r

i want to rotate a data.frame in R. my dataframe looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame( A = c("Att1","Att2"), b = c(12,10), c =c(8,9), d =c (1,2))
```

and in the end my dataframe should looks like following:

```
d2 <- data.frame( name = c("B","C","D"), Att1 = c(10,8,1), Attr2 = c(10,9,2))
```

I already tried to use the t()-method, but there is always this error: 
Column `d` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

how can i perform the rotate operation on the dataframe?
Thanks for any help!
regards

Comment: In base R, `setNames(data.frame(t(as.matrix(d[-1]))), as.character(d[[1]]))`. where the A variable will be the row.names. If desired, you could extract them and put them in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first transpose it and then follow below steps

```r
library(tibble)

df <- data.frame(t(d), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df) <- df[1, ]                #assign 1st row to column name
df <- df[-1, ]
df <- rownames_to_column(df, "name")  #assign row name to a new column
```

gives

```
> df
  name Att1 Att2
1    b   12   10
2    c    8    9
3    d    1    2
```

**Sample data:**

```
d <- structure(list(A = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Att1", "Att2"), class = "factor"), 
    b = c(12, 10), c = c(8, 9), d = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```